# Capturar coordenadas de un click en un frame

Tags: java, jframe, mouselistener

Buenas noches bros soy nuevo en esta plataforma, disculpen si no formulo bien mi pregunta, quisiera exponerles una duda que tengo sobre una tarea que me dejaron: ***La actividad consiste en realizar un programa con interfaz gráfica que capture la coordenada donde el usuario haga clic.***

He realizado el programa con mi poca experiencia, aquí les dejo mi código, **el problema es que debo de capturar las coordenadas del click respecto a la resolución de la ventana** y en mi programa se capturan las coordenadas del click en mi escritorio.

¿Mi idea del código esta mal? Alguna sugerencia que me puedan dar para corregir mi error. Muchas gracias de antemano. Les adjunto una foto de como esta el programa actualmente.

```
package coordenada;

import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Coordenada extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

boolean b; 
JLabel n1;

public Coordenada() {
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tu Coordenada");
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    
//  Atributos

    n1 = new JLabel();
    n1.setBounds(70, 5, 200, 50);
    b = true;
    texto();        
    
//  Integracion de los atributos

    frame.add(n1);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.addMouseListener(this);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
}

public void texto() {
    n1.setText("Cliquea en donde quieras:");
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    
    while (b) { 
        
        // Se obtiene el objeto de información del puntero del mouseInfo
        PointerInfo pi = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo(); 

        // Se obtiene la locacion del mouse 
        Point p = pi.getLocation(); 

        // Se inserta la ubicacion del mouse
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Posicion x = "+p.getX()+" Posicion y = "+p.getY());
        
        return;
}
      
/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/

/** 
* Marca error el metodo principal porque esta en una clase abstracta para el uso de la interfaz MouseListener,
* pero no impide el funcionamiento del programa   
*/

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Coordenada c = new Coordenada();
    
}

// Metodos abstractos de la interfaz MouseListener

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a lo que se refiere Java en su documentación:

> getLocation() -->
> Returns the Point that represents the coordinates of the pointer on the screen.

El método que utilizas "getLocation()" te proporciona coordenadas de acuerdo a la resolución de tu pantalla en general (monitor).

Si quieres que Java te proporcione las coordenadas de acuerdo al área que abarca un componente necesitas especificar "que componente" debe proporcionar esas coordenadas. Dicho de otra manera debes indicar que las coordenadas que tu deseas son en relación a tu marco de la aplicación (JFrame):

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

while (b) { 
    // Se inserta la ubicacion del mouse
    double x = arg0.getX();
    double y = arg0.getY();
    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Posicion x = "+x+" Posicion y = "+y);
    
    return;
}
```

Como puedes apreciar en el código que te proporciono, utilizo la variable "arg0" de tipo "MouseEvent", con el accedo a las coordenadas desde el componente donde el mouse fue accionado, en este caso el JFrame.

Te invito a revisar la documentación oficial de Java para un mejor entendimiento acerca de los métodos que contiene cada interfaz y clase asociada a estos eventos del mouse:

[MouseListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent))

[MouseEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getPoint())

En adicional puedes comparar la documentación de la clase que anteriormente usabas con la que te estoy proporcionando para que tu mismo puedas notar las diferencias:
[PointerInfo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/PointerInfo.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda hermano, error mío no haber leído correctamente la documentación completa. Saludos y nueva mente muchas gracias.